# Specifying Terminal-only mapping in Karabiner

Tags: terminal, keybindings

I am trying to remap specific `Ctrl+<Key>` combinations to `Command+<Key>` in Terminal.app using Karabiner. The following `private.xml` is used:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Swap Ctrl+S and Cmd+S</name>
    <identifier>private.filters_cmd</identifier>
    <only>TERMINAL</only>

    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

For now only `Ctrl+S` is remapped. However, it only works if no application-level filtering is set via `<only>`. And i would want those mappings to be active only in Terminal.app.

Probably there is something wrong with my definition. Can someone please advise?

I am using OS X 10.11.3.

Answer (score 2):

My bad. I had to enable AXNotifier in Karabiner, and allow it access in `System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Accessibility`. Hopefully the above will be helpful for others.

Sometimes posting a question helps resolving it by the very fact of posting it:)

**UPDATE**: [Here](https://github.com/siphiuel/dotfiles/blob/master/karabiner_private.xml) is Karabiner's `private.xml` i'm currently using , in case someone would find it useful. It maps almost all of `Ctrl+<Key>` combinations, except for some that might still be useful (e.g. `Cmd+Q`, `Cmd+N`, `Cmd+M`).